# Create an array with a fixed size, and fill default content with another array?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I want to create a fixed size array with a default number of elements already filled from another array, so lets say that I have this method:

```
def fixed_array(size, other)
  array = Array.new(size)
  other.each_with_index { |x, i| array[i] = x }
  array
end
```

So then I can use the method like:

```
fixed_array(5, [1, 2, 3])
```

And I will get

```
[1, 2, 3, nil, nil]
```

Is there an easier way to do that in ruby? Like expanding the current size of the array I already have with nil objects?

Comment: Do you want a new array, or expand an existing array? Which?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
def fixed_array(size, other)  
   Array.new(size) { |i| other[i] }
end
fixed_array(5, [1, 2, 3])
# => [1, 2, 3, nil, nil]
```

Comment: Is this possible only for particular index ?

Answer (score 12):

```
5.times.collect{|i| other[i]}
 => [1, 2, 3, nil, nil]
```

Answer (score 5):

> Is there an easier way to do that in ruby? Like expanding the current size of the array I already have with nil objects?

Yes, you can expand your current array by setting the last element via [`Array#[]=`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D):

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
a[4] = nil # index is zero based
a
# => [1, 2, 3, nil, nil]
```

A method could look like this:

```
def grow(ary, size)
  ary[size-1] = nil if ary.size < size
  ary
end
```

Note that this will modify the passed array.

Answer (score 3):

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a.dup
Array.new(5){b.shift} # => [1, 2, 3, nil, nil]
```

Or

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = Array.new(5)
b[0...a.length] = a
b # => [1, 2, 3, nil, nil]
```

Or

```
Array.new(5).zip([1, 2, 3]).map(&:last) # => [1, 2, 3, nil, nil]
```

Or

```
Array.new(5).zip([1, 2, 3]).transpose.last # => [1, 2, 3, nil, nil]
```

Answer (score 3):

Similar to the answer by @xaxxon, but even shorter:

```
5.times.map {|x| other[x]}
```

or

```
(0..4).map {|x| other[x]}
```

Comment: or `(0...5)` (with three dots)

Answer (score 2):

You can also do the following:
(assuming `other = [1,2,3]`)

```
(other+[nil]*5).first(5)
=> [1, 2, 3, nil, nil]
```

if other is [], you get

```
(other+[nil]*5).first(5)
=> [nil, nil, nil, nil]
```

Answer (score 1):

this answer uses the `fill` method

```
def fixed_array(size, other, default_element=nil)
  _other = other
  _other.fill(default_element, other.size..size-1)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this? So you don't create a new array.

```
def fixed_array(size, other)
  (size - other.size).times { other << nil }
end
```